# Is it possible to "reverse" php str_shuffe?

Tags: php, reverse, shuffle

I was just wondering if it's possible to reverse the string shuffle function in php?

For Example:

```
$shuffle = str_shuffle("popcorn");
echo $shuffle;
```

If you refreshed the page 3 times, you might see something like this:

- oroppcn
- oppncro
- opcrnop

etc...

Is there a way to "Scrabble" that back into "popcorn"?

Comment: You're aware that it's *randomized* output? There's no reproducible algorithm, so no "unshuffling" it.

Comment: I don't think so. You will have to create a class or something to store the original unshuffled string.

Comment: I deleted a comment about storing it in a session/cookie so I rewrote it but with more. What you *could* do is use a session (or cookie) and increase its number by 1 each time and storing the original string in a session array. Once it hits the 3rd shuffle from a conditional statement, show the original string. I could write this out, but I rather let you try and it figure it out so you can learn. If you hit a wall somewhere, you can get more help.

Comment: No worries, thanks for the ideas everyone

Comment: Interesting exercise that I'm stealing for a programming course I teach :) That said, if you have a dictionary of valid words, you could do some educated guessing with character counts... crap. now i have to go write code. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If we are talking about canceling the str_shuffle action, then this is not possible despite the fact that the php documentation says: "This function does not generate cryptographically secure values". Reversing the rand algorithm used in str_shuffle is a non-trivial cryptographic task.

But let's fantasize. Suppose if we have a dictionary, then we can do this:

```
<?php

$list = array('apple', 'popcorn', 'banana');

$shuffle = str_shuffle("popcorn");

$letters = count_chars($shuffle,1);
foreach ($list as $word) {
  if ($letters == count_chars($word,1))
    echo "$word\n";
}
```

[DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ed7f8623a984302633dad74a13cf927907366268)